# How can i get an image of a city with Google Places API?

Tags: android, google-places-api

It's quite easy in Android and Swift to get an image for famous sights and attractions via Google Places API.
But it is not possible to get an image from a whole city.

For Example:
When using the Google Place id of a sight (e.g. the Brandenburger Gate, with a Place Id of "ChIJiQnyVcZRqEcRY0xnhE77uyY") the Google Places API returns an image.
But when using the Google Place Id of a city (e.g. New York, with a Place Id of "ChIJOwg_06VPwokRYv534QaPC8g") the Google Places Api does not return any image.

Does anybody know if it is posible to get an image from a city? When yes, how can i achieve this using Java (Android)?

UPDATE: This problem does not exist anymore, it looks like google did some changes here. Now The Place API returns images for cities as well.

Comment: Yes, we did recently improve this.  Glad you noticed :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly find a id for particular place using this url https://developers.google.com/places/place-id

then after getting the id find details for that place using Place details url.
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

Comment: Yes, that's correct.
But when using the place id of a city, e.g. New York, the place details url does not return any image.
When using the place id of a attraction, e.g. the rockefeller center it works and returns an image.

It is not working with cities, that's the problem. Maybe someone knows about another service that returns city images?